# Unable to generate a URL for the named route

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

> CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has
>   been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a
>   URL for the named route "Metaflex_Metaflex_analysis" as such route
>   does not exist.") in "::base.html.twig" at line 159.

This error occurs again and again even if I change the controller name path. But still it's having an issue, why?

Comment: Does this happen in the `dev` or in the `prod` environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need that the params that the route need and you have pass in the twig are the same. Ex.

```
//Controller

/**
* @Route("/{id}/{time}", name="index")
*/
public function holaAction($id,$time){
}

//TWIG
<a href="{{path("index",{'id':1,'time':9999})}}">Link</a>
```